# Magento 2.2.5. What would be the correct way to update a price based on tier pricing

Tags: product, magento2.2, tierprice

Is there a way to update the product price based on user selection when I have enabled tier pricing in a product? For example, in the below image, if the user enters 5 in the `Qty` box, the price gets updated with the correct price, ie. 180.00.

[image]

Comment: You need to write custom javascript to make it work.

Comment: Any ideas how to start with this custom module?